# Data passed by POST between angular and python flask is empty

Tags: python, angular, post

I am trying to create a 'pipe' between an angular frontend and a python flask backend. I have managed to communicate from the former to the latter by `HttpClient.get` calls but updating that to `HttpClient.post` breaks the communication. My code looks like:

- on the Angular side:

  ```
  let request =
  this.HttpClient.post(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/weather/loc`,
  {
    "location": this.location,
  })

  request.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data); })
  ```

and on the flask side:

```
@app.route('/weather/loc', methods=["POST"])
def weather_connection():
    print( request.form)
    location = request.form.get("location", default="London")
    #more code
```

The problem I see is that `request.form` is always `ImmutableMultiDict([])` an empty dictionary. For some reason the `location` argument seems to have been lost somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's HttpClient posts data in JSON format. But Flask's `request.data` is only for data that is form-encoded. Instead, you should use `request.get_json()`.

Comment: Indeed, using `location = request.json["location"]` does the trick. Many thanks!